# Android FTP proxy settings

Tags: android

I would like to ask if it is possible to set FTP proxy of android device? I can only see applications that can set HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS. I haven't seen for FTP proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives to have partial support of proxy in Android are listed here: http://issue1273.blogspot.com. There is also an Android Proxy Library that try to abstract and make easier the access to proxy settings for every Android version. You can try to ask for a support of FTP protocol.